# CSS - apply unicode range to brower-installed font

Tags: css

I want to set a unicode range to *Consolas*, a monospace font installed in most browsers. Instead linking an external font file by `src`, I want to use the font file *which is already in the browser*. How should I edit the CSS below?

I have checked many sources from StackOverflow and other sites about applying Unicode range to @font-face, but could not find useful advice for this specific matter. Any help will be appreciated.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Consolas";
  src: browser???;
  unicode-range: U+0061-0100;
}
```

**Edit**: I have tried using `src: local('Consolas');` but it didn't seem to work, strangely.

Comment: If you only want to use a local font, you can use `local('Consolas')`. What exactly do you want to achieve by specifying the unicode range? Will there be other font-face definitions for different unicode ranges of Consolas? Otherwise, if you only want to use a local font without any web font source, you could do without `@font-face`  and only use `font-family: Consolas`; (probably with a fallback like `font-family: Consolas, monospace;')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [local()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face#Description), an example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'CustomConsolas';
  src: local('Consolas');
  unicode-range: U+0061-0100;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad that this works! Actually I have tried `src: local('Consolas');` before, but what I havent tried is naming the font family as **Custom**Consolas. Setting the font-family simply as Consolas didn't seem to work. What is the difference?

Comment: @Henry5400 I guess it's because if you use `Consolas` the browser looks for the font installed in your machine rather than your custom `@font-face` definition. So you must use a different `font-family`.